# Upgraded from VS 2008 to VS 2010, checked into SVN, still prompting to upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, svn

Like the title says, we upgraded our VS2008 solution to VS2010 and checked in the updated solution file to SVN.  When I update my local SVN with the changes, and open the solution in VS2010, I still get the "upgrade wizard" prompt telling me the solution needs to be upgraded to VS2010 even though the `.sln` file has already been upgraded.  Trying to open it back in VS2008 gives the expected error that the solution is for a newer version of Visual Studio.

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it so we don't have to run the upgrade wizard on a solution that's already been upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the root of your problem, but it is worth trying.
When a VS2008 project is converted by the wizard (when you convert a solution, the projects get converted as well), a file is created for each project file, with the same name but a different extension: `vcxproj` instead of `vcproj`. This file is not versioned by the SVN (since it didn't exist before the wizard did his thing), so it is missing when you SVN-update your solution on the computer where the wizard didn't run.

So, add and commit to the SVN repository all the `vcxproj` files that were created by the wizard, update the other working copy, and try opening the solution again in VS2010. Btw, the old `vcproj` files are not needed anymore, so you can remove them from the SVN repository if you are sure no one will need the VS2008 version.